# Error during artifact deployment

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to deploy an application in Wildfly 10 but I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -classpath /opt/jetbrains/idea-IU-163.13906.18/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/jetbrains/idea-IU-163.13906.18/lib/util.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /tmp/classpath com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 42364 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
[2017-10-05 12:50:04,818] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : skin.war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
[2017-10-05 12:50:04,818] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : drcs-development.war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Oct 05, 2017 12:50:04 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
Oct 05, 2017 12:50:04 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
Oct 05, 2017 12:50:04 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
[2017-10-05 12:50:05,133] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : skin.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-10-05 12:50:05,133] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : drcs-development.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:44287', transport: 'socket'
[2017-10-05 12:50:08,064] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : skin.war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-10-05 12:50:08,064] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : skin.war: Deploy took 2,931 milliseconds
[2017-10-05 12:50:15,349] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : drcs-development.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-10-05 12:50:15,350] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner.api : drcs-development.war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"drcs-development.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"drcs-development.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"drcs-development.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/solveralynx/wildrunner_api/drcs/business_impl/ejb/jobs/GBMeteringDataJobEJB (Module \"deployment.drcs-development.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): com/solveralynx/wildrunner_api/drcs/business_api/ejb/jobs/MeteringDataJobLocal"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"drcs-development.war\".POST_MODULE"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

My wildfly deployment structure looks like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the war's module, for an ear -->
    <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder -->
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <!--<module name="com.google.guava" slot="main"/>-->
        </exclusions>

    <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same as using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.google.gwt.user" slot="main" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.google.gwt.servlet" slot="main" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j" slot="main" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xalan" slot="main"/>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- These add additional classes to the module. In this case it is the same as including the jar in the EAR's lib directory -->

    <resources>
    </resources>
</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="web.war">
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
        <module name="com.google.gwt.user" slot="main"/>
        <module name="com.google.gwt.servlet" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.xnio" slot="main"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>

<sub-deployment name="business-impl.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.xnio" slot="main"/>
        <module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I don't know what causes this error to happen. I'm thinking that I have to change POST_MODULE phase into something different.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a class could not be linked: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/solveralynx/wildrunner_api/drcs/business_impl/ejb/jobs/GBMeteringDataJobEJB (Module \"deployment.drcs-development.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): com/solveralynx/wildrunner_api/drcs/business_api/ejb/jobs/MeteringDataJobLocal". What is the layout of your deployment? Is it possible that the war classes do not "see" the EJB classes?

Comment: I've found the solution. The problem is that I din't build artifact drcs-development.war before running the gradle task developmentLocalApiWar so basically I had an empty war in it.